# "General HTTP Error" for XML sitemap in Google search console

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, http, error

Google search console says that the XML sitemap specified in [robots.txt](http://voicetotranslate.com/robots.txt)  could not be read due to:

> General HTTP Error

[image]

When I click on the link on right top, "OPEN SITEMAP," it shows an error:

> No input file specified

but when I copy the link of my sitemap and paste it into my browser, it shows up just fine.  It seems somehow that Google can not reach the sitemap. What should I do?

Comment: "What should I do?" Maybe start by giving out the URL of your sitemap so that others can double check everything is right? Otherwise, besides asking Google directly, I am not sure anyone can help you with such amount of details.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you very much. This is robots link http://voicetotranslate.com/robots.txt

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I really appreciate if you can help. It is a Test URL

Comment: Did you already try all the steps outlined at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451001#errors ? Besides there are no URLs in the sitemap you present, and extra heading/trailing spaces in the "loc" part.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you very very much for your care. I will check the link. Thank you for sharing. For site map , let me ask you to be sure , this is the link of site map , http://voicetotranslate.com/sitemap.xml and there is some data on it includes the link of main page. Should I change it? and next question , what do you mean of extra heading spaces in loc part? what is loc part? Thank you and Thank you thousand times

Comment: Your site doesn't need a sitemap at all.  They aren't needed for SEO.  They can help get Google to fully crawl large sites, but they don't usually help get pages indexed or ranked.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox). On a small crawlable site, a sitemap is useless and redundant.  Having just one page in your sitemap is silly.   Using an online sitemap generator defeats the purpose of the sitemap.  If the generator can crawl your site to produce the sitemap, then Googlebot can crawl it too and there is no need for the sitemap.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for great information. I understand, But The problem is that all my websites confronts this situation awhile all of them was working and indexing by google until last week very well, I love to fix it . the result is not very important